# Latex Commands ignored while rendering html

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

When a .Rmd file is being knit into html, latex commands are completely ignored. Itemize, quotes, even text formatting disappers, along with the text. When knitting to .pdf \chapter is declared to be undefined control sequence and the execution is halted.

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_md: yes
    theme: cerulean
    toc: yes
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    toc: yes
---
\chapter{{Efficient R Coding}}

\section{Benchmarking}

Donald Knuth\sidenote{See \url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth}} made the following statement on optimization:
  \begin{quote}
\textit{"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97\% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."}
\end{quote}
\noindent So before we rush headlong into optimising our R code, we will spend some time determining when it is worthwhile optimising. In this chapter, we will look at benchmarking. In computing, a benchmark is obtained by running a set of programs in order to assess their relative performance.

\section{Simple benchmarks}

To construct a benchmark we typically use the following steps
\begin{enumerate}
\item Construct a function (or set of functions) around the feature we want to
benchmark. This function usually has an argument that allows us to vary the
complexity of the object. For example, a parameter \texttt{n} that alters the data
```

This is renders as...

[image: Notice that chapter definition and the quote is missing]

Enumerate environment is ignored. Section and chapter titles are also ignored. How to make pandoc render the content enclosed in the curly brackets?

Comment: you are supposed to write markdown, not latex when using knitr... (or maybe there's a way to specify the input format as latex)

Comment: Yep. I suspected as such. If I had written the document, I would've followed that rule.  Any way of making pandoc understand Latex formatting commands? Latex Math environments are well understood and rendered, but formatting commands (such as quote environment) are ignored. I know you are supposed to use Markdown commands for that business, but is there any way of making the latex commands understandable?

Comment: i don't know knitr (which somehow uses pandoc internally), but on the command line: `pandoc input.tex -o output.md` does convert the tex to markdown, see http://pandoc.org